# Segmentation fault in depth-first search for big graphs in c

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I have the following recursive implementation of the depth-first search. At the end the array pre shows in which order the several vertices were visited. I want to run it for really big graphs. In this example: n = 2097152, m = 6291408. G is represented as an adjacency list.

```
static int cnt, pre[2097152];
static link t;

void dfsRAdjazenz(Graph G, Edge e)
{ 
    int w = e.w 
    pre[w] = cnt++; 

    for (t = G->adj[w]; t != NULL; t = t->next) {
        if (pre[t->v] == -1) {            
            Edge e = {w, t->v};
            dfsRAdjazenz(G, e); 
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{   
    cnt=0;
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < 2097152; v++) {
        pre[v] = -1;
    }

    Edge e = {1,1};
    dfsRAdjazenz(G, e);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is I always run out of memory -> segmentation fault, although there is really enough memory available. It just works for around about 1million nodes.

Edit: the data structures:

```
typedef struct node *link;  

struct node { 
    int v; 
    link next; 
};

struct graph { 
    int V; 
    int E; 
    link *adj; 
};

typedef struct { 
    int v; 
    int w; 
} Edge;

typedef struct graph *Graph;
```

Comment: Why are you hiding the most important code from us, namely the definitions of the types `Graph` and `Edge`? Is this a guessing game? The answer is probably "you're using your data structures wrong", but that is precisely the information you've *not* posted.

Comment: What are `n` and `m` stand for?

Comment: sry, I updated it. n = nodes, m = edges

Comment: Are you sure you are running out of memory -- is that the message or do you just get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be due to the recursion you are using, you are exhausting the stack. if the graph is not sparse then the recursion can be very deep, and it also explains why it works with small values.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as odd

```
t = G->adj[w]
```

You are using array indexing into what looks to be a linked list.

I'd expect that to seg fault for any value other than 1.

Of course it is hard to tell without seeing the definition of G.

Comment: I added the definition of graph or what do you mean? I read G from a file and that doesn't cause problems. t = G->adj[w] works great for less nodes and edges.

Comment: err... really?  Ok.. when you allocate space for G->adj how do you do it?